# One query for multiple views data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an application which uses listbox entries from a Oracle Database.
When loading application uses from 5 to 10 connections to the database in order to get all the listbox values and is a bit slow at the beginning.

I came up with an idea to fetch all data in one query and then add each column to the right listbox. However I am not sure if it is possible and if yes how to do that. I have tried to find a solution on the google and on SO but no matches found.

Data from different tables is not related in any way - it is just a list of words or IDs needed later.

Typical SQL query tries to join data and that is not the outcome I am looking for, below sample code.

```
  SELECT
  desk.id_number as desk_id,
  desk.name as desk_name,
  sub.id as subpurpose_id,
  sub.sub_purpose as subpurpose_name

  FROM
  desk_table desk,
  sub_table sub
```

...and this is data I would like to achieve.

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| desk_id | desk_name | subpurpose_id | subpurpose_name |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1 | desk1     |            11 | sub11           |
|       2 | desk2     |            12 | sub12           |
|       3 | desk3     |            13 | sub13           |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you CAN do this, although I think it's messy and I wouldn't recommend it.

```
SELECT
desk.id_number as desk_id,
desk.name as desk_name,
sub.id as subpurpose_id,
sub.sub_purpose as subpurpose_name
FROM
(select desk_table.*, rownum rn from desk_table) desk
FULL OUTER JOIN (select sub_table.*, rownum rn from sub_table) sub
ON desk.rn = sub.rn
```

The problem is that since your tables aren't actually related at all, you would naturally want to do a `cross join`, but that will give you every combination of results from both tables - so you want to filter it to match up *row 1 from table1* with *row 1 from table2*, etc.

EDIT: I updated it to work when you have different numbers of rows in each table - for this you want a full outer join.

In your scenario, I'd recommend using a UNION with an added column that just describes which listbox each row belongs to. It's much easier to read and maintain.

```
SELECT 'DESK' as listbox, id_number as id, name
FROM desk_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUBPURPOSE', id as id, sub_purpose as name
FROM sub_table
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, however it does not work. Maybe I should have mentioned that each table has different amount of records? For now I get only as many record as desk_table has which is like 8 and other table has 50+ records.

Comment: Your recommendation is interesting however my tables are not always the same type and it screams for error.

Comment: Oh right, updated to work with different amounts of records in each table.

Comment: That is excacly what I was looking for. Thank you and a big plus for an alternative solution.